# How do I execute a method from a library jar on a different JRE than my current project's JRE

Tags: java, jce

I have a project 1 which need to run on 1.7, this project has a dependency on another project 2 built on 1.8.

I am trying to invoke a class from Project 2 inside Project 1, but I am getting a known error which is fixed in 1.8. I f I run this class individually on Project 2 in JRE 1.8, it works fine.

Any leads to chose the target JRE dynamically for a method call?

Comment: When you chose 1.7 as JRE for your program, the code of Project 2 referenced by Project 1 gets executed in the same JRE, naturally. If you want to have the Projects ran in different JRE, you have to have two Java processes and some kind of communication mechanism between these two programs.

Comment: Are you compiling your projects into jars before trying to call them? If so, depending on what jar wrapper you use, you can Bundle a jre path. To be clear, that means that you place a jre inside your project, so it doesn't need a system wide jre to run. Just make sure you select the option, "Only use private JRE runtimes" when wrapping.

If this helps, let me know, and I'll post this with images and more detail as an answer. I just wasn't 100% this would suit your needs.

Comment: @Terry I will try right away

Comment: It would still mean you would have to package a JRE 1.8, else the code from project 2 will still fail to execute. If the requirement is for project 1 to run on 1.7, this approach won't work.

Comment: @RakeshS I have successfully tested and accomplished two programs running on different JREs just now, however they are both wrapped jar files. Will that solve your problem? If that works for you, I don't mind writing an answer. I used Launch4j by the way.

Comment: Why not run everything under JRE 1.8 (what obscure removed feature could you be relying on that is in Java 7 and not 8)?

Comment: @TerryDorsey Can you please write that answer. I tried using the basic eclipse tools but couldn't work it out.

Comment: @Strelok My project1 is built in a version of openscript which supports 1.7 only for now. Cipher AES-GCM isn't supported in 1.7 but started support from 1.8. I am checking a workaround for that issue as well in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to make a jar and use a wrapper for each program, you can bundle a specific jre with each executable.

1. Download and run [Launch4j](https://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/)
2. In your eclipse project, click on:

   `File -> export -> runnable jar file -> next`

   And select the run configuration for the project you'd like to extract. Hit `Finish`
3. It's a good idea to test each jar and make sure it runs. Double click, or find it with cmd and do `java -jar nameOfJarToTest.jar`.
4. Make a subfolder for your jre. I just called mine "jre".
5. Copy and paste your `bin` and `lib` folders from the correct jre into that folder you just made. Mine are located in a place like `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201` if you wanted to run java 8. To be extra clear, your file structure should be

> someContainerFolder(folder you just made)
>
> ```
>   nameOfJarToTest.jar
>
>   jre(folder you just made)
>
>         bin(folder copied from the jre in your file system)
>
>         lib(folder copied from the jre in your file system)
> ```

6. Run Launch4j. Add the .jar and select an output file path. Fields pictured below 
   [image]
7. Click on the jre tab and add your respective jre in the `min jre` field. Make sure you select the option `Only use private jdk runtimes`. Type "jre"(if you named the folder with 'bin' and 'lib' jre) in the "bundled jre path" field pictured below.

[image]

8. Click on 'build wrapper'. It looks like a settings cog. 
   [image]

If you do this for both jar files, and make sure the 'bin' and 'lib' folders are from the jre you want to run, the two programs will both run fine in different runtime environments. If you would like one program to be able to call the other, I found the geeksforgeeks website has [a very simple and concise way for you to call external executable files from your code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calling-external-program-java-using-process-runtime/) if you're okay with canonical paths.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, if your project depends on 1.7 it's dependencies should also be 1.7. At runtime all code executes in the same JVM, there is no way to dynamically 'choose' a target JRE.

If you really have no other option and the two libraries should work together, you could possibly build some kind of bridge between project 1 and 2, where project 1 invokes project 2 in a separate JVM instance.